# Cleaning up a list of folders, only keeping the top-level folder from each group of folders

Tags: python, string, list, optimization

I have just started programming Python and hope some of you experienced could give me
a hint about how to optimizing the code below.

What I am trying to do is to go through a list of folders making a new list only containing the top-level folder from each group of folders.

I have struggled and written the code below, which does the job, but scale terribly when used lists containing thousands of folders.

Any ides how to optimize this routine are most welcome.

```
folderlist = [  "c:\\temp\\data\\1122 AA",\
                "c:\\temp\\data\\1122 AA\\Div",\
                "c:\\temp\\data\\1122 AA\\Div\\Etc",\
                "c:\\temp\\data\\1122 AA\\Div\\Etc2",\
                "c:\\temp\\server1\\div\\2244_BB",\
                "c:\\temp\\server1\\div\\2244_BB\\pp",\
                "c:\\temp\\server1\\div\\2244_BB\\der\\dedd",\
                "c:\\temp\\server1\\div\\2244_BB\\defwe23d\\23ded",\
                "c:\\temp\\123456789-BB",\
                "c:\\temp\\123456789-BB\\pp",\
                "c:\\temp\\123456789-BB\\der\\dee32d",\
                "c:\\temp\\data\\123456789-BB\\ded\\ve_23"]

l2 = folderlist.copy()
ind = []
indexes_to_be_deleted = []

for el in l2:
    for idx, x in enumerate(l2):
        if el in x:
            ind.append(idx)

counts = Counter(ind)

for l, count in counts.most_common():
    if count > 1:
        indexes_to_be_deleted.append(l)    

for i in sorted(indexes_to_be_deleted, reverse=True): 
    del folderlist[i]

Output:
c:\\temp\\data\\1122 AA\\
c:\\temp\\server1\\div\\2244_BB\\
c:\\temp\\123456789-BB\\
```

The output is as expected, only the top-level folder from each group of folders. However, I hope some of you have an idea how to make the routine faster.

Comment: Try using os module, for example if you want to list all top-level directories from a certain path, you can try something like this:                                                                        `for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):                                                                                           
      if os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+"/"+i):
         print(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding to a new list rather than removing items:

```
topFolders = [] 
for name in folderlist:  # sorted(folderlist) if they are not already in order
    if topFolders and name.startswith(topFolders[-1]+"\\"): continue
    topFolders.append(name)
```

you can assign it to the original list if necessary

```
folderlist = topFolders
```

Comment: Thank you for that elegant solution Alian!
It works perfectly.

Comment: Actually there IS an issue with it as it will skip top folders that have a name that begins with the name of another top folder.  Easily fixed by appending a backslash to the last topfolder name in the condition (which changed in my post)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post my somewhat over-engineered, recursive, tree-based solution since (a) I wrote it before seeing (and upvoting) Alain T.'s answer, and (b) because I think it should be *asymptotically* faster for unsorted input (`O(n)` vs `O(n.log(n))`) than sorting the list - though for mere thousands of paths sorting may well be faster than all this hashing etc.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def new_node():
    return defaultdict(new_node)

def insert_into_tree(tree, full_path, split_path):
    top_dir, *rest_of_path = split_path

    if isinstance(tree[top_dir], str):
        # A shorter path is already in the tree! Throw this path away.
        return None

    if not rest_of_path:
        # Store the full path at this leaf.
        tree[top_dir] = full_path
        return full_path

    return insert_into_tree(tree[top_dir], full_path, rest_of_path)

def get_shortest_paths(tree, paths):
    for dir_name, child in tree.items():
        if isinstance(child, str):
            paths.append(child)
        else:
            get_shortest_paths(child, paths)

folder_list = [ ... ]
folder_tree = new_node()

for full_path in folder_list:
    insert_into_tree(folder_tree, full_path, full_path.split("\\"))

shortest_paths = []
get_shortest_paths(folder_tree, shortest_paths)

print(shortest_paths)
```